# How to disable(hide) Optional Content Group(OCG) using Pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to disable the OCG using pdfbox. I tried below code, but it is not disabling the OCG. Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void OCGDelete(PDDocument doc, String OCName) throws IOException {

        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDOptionalContentProperties props= catalog.getOCProperties();
        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        List<String> ocgNames = Lists.newArrayList(props.getGroupNames());
        if(ocgNames.contains(OCGName)) {
            PDOptionalContentGroup group = props.getGroup(OCGName);
            props.setGroupEnabled(group, **false**);
        }

        doc.getDocumentCatalog().setOCProperties(props);

        doc.save(pdfOutStream);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("test/emitted/OCGResult.pdf"));
        out.write(pdfOutStream.toByteArray());
        out.close();
```

Comment: Please share your PDF and mention what PDFBox version you are using (hopefully 2.0.16). Btw you can save directly to a file, i.e. `doc.save(new File("test/emitted/OCGResult.pdf"));`

Comment: I am using Pdfbox 2.0.14. Sorry, Unfortunately PDF is confidential, I can't share it. Please let me know the better Pdfbox version to work.

Comment: As I wrote: 2.0.16. Please try a public file with OCGs, e.g. https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12893415/pdf_layer_new.pdf , and tell what you try to disable. Use PDFDebugger to find the names.